# wso2: Unsupported access token type

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am following this link https://github.com/sagara-gunathunga/oauth-filter/tree/master/OAuth2Filter to protect my web, which protected fine by end user. But when I am trying to access resources with access token I get **Unsupported access token type**, I am generating my access token from rest client and my web application is deployed on tomcat.

please help

Comment: Can you provide the error log and details on how you generate the access token?

Comment: I am generating access token from Rest Client, and in my wso2is console it giving only Unsupported access token type, But One thing I observe that in TokenValidationClient class, ConfigurationContext is returning null. So please aasist me how to do that. thank you

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/master/modules/samples/oauth2/playground2/src/main/org/wso2/sample/identity/oauth2/OAuth2ServiceClient.java

Answer (score 0):

According to Error "Unsupported access token type" correct token validator is not picked up while validating access token type "bearer". Did you do any changes to `<TokenValidators>` element is identity.xml.
Please restore default configuration

```
<TokenValidator type="bearer" class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.DefaultOAuth2TokenValidator"/>
```

and see how it works.